# Oracle10.2のデータベースをOracle19cに移行したい

Tags: oracle

すいません。
初めて質問させて頂きます。
Windows Server(R) 2003 R2にOracle10g(10.2)のデータベースをWindows Server(R) 2019のOracle19cに移行したいと
考えてます。
Windows Server(R) 2003 R2上で、エクスポートしたダンプデータから、Windows Server(R) 2019に移行するようなイメージで取られてますが、Oracleのバージョンがかなり上がってますので、簡単には移行できないと思い、質問させて
頂きました。
何方か助言や回答を頂ければ幸いです。
宜しくお願いします。

Comment: かなりバージョンが離れていますね、テーブルのスキーマは新環境であらかじめ作っておいて、データだけexpdp/inpdpするのが安全(トラブルがすくない)な気がします。新環境とおなじ環境を作って試してみるのが確実だと思います。

Comment: 助言ありがとうございます